# Flattening nested observables and include regular variables in outer observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, flatmap, switchmap

Sorry to clarify, the following data structure:

```
const obs = Observable.fromPromise(firebase.storage().ref('Test').child('logo.png').getDownloadURL());

const json = {
  obs: obs,
  test: 1
};
const obs2 = Observable.of(
  json
);
```

So that would leave me with the following for obs2:

```
{…}:
   obs: Object { _isScalar: false, promise: {…}, scheduler: undefined }
   test: 1
```

I've been having trouble getting this obs2 stream flattened while also keeping the test variable as part of the structure.
Ideally I should be working with a format that looks like:

```
{…}:
   url: 'url',
   test: 1
```

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right, it seems to me that this should do it:

```
obs2 = json.obs.map(url => { url, test: json.test })
```